# c++ Overload operator bool() gives an ambiguous overload error with operator+

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, boolean

I'm compiling some c++ code of a class MegaInt which is a positive decimal type class that allows arithmetic operations on huge numbers.

I want to overload operator bool to allow code like this:

```
MegaInt m(45646578676547676);  
if(m)  
    cout << "YaY!" << endl;
```

This is what I did:

header:

```
class MegaInt
{
    public:
        ...
    operator bool() const;
};

const MegaInt operator+(const MegaInt & left, const MegaInt & right);
const MegaInt operator*(const MegaInt & left, const MegaInt & right);
```

implementation:

```
MegaInt::operator bool() const
{
    return *this != 0;
}
const MegaInt operator+(const MegaInt & left, const MegaInt & right)
{
    MegaInt ret = left;
    ret += right;
    return ret;
}
```

Now, the problem is if I do:

```
MegaInt(3424324234234342) + 5;
```

It gives me this error:

> ambiguous overload for 'operator+' in 'operator+(const MegaInt&, const MegaInt&)
>   note: candidates are: operator+(int, int) |
>   note:                 const MegaInt operator+(const MegaInt&, const MegaInt&)|

I don't know why. How is the overloaded bool() causing operator+ to become ambiguous?¸

Thank You.

---

Well, everyone gave me great answers, unfortunately, none of them seem to solve my problem entirely.

**Both void* or the Safe Bool Idiom works.** Except for one tiny problem, I hope has a workaround:

When comparing with 0 like:

```
if (aMegaInt == 0)
```

The compiler gives an ambiguous overload error again. I understand why: it doesn't know if we're comparing to false or to MegaInt of value 0. None the less, in that case, I'd want it to cast to MegaInt(0). Is there a way to force this?

Thank You Again.

Comment: Might need to use the [safe bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool).

Comment: It seems the safe bool idiom has a cleaner alternative now if you are using C++11: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete-in-c11

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The C++ compiler is allowed to automatically convert `bool` into `int` for you, and that's what it wants to do here.

The way to solve this problem is to employ the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

Technically, creating an `operator void*` is **not** an example of the safe bool idiom, but it's safe enough in practice, because the bool/int problem you're running into is a common error, and messes up some perfectly reasonable and otherwise correct code (as you see from your question), but misuses of the `void*` conversion are not so common.

Comment: +1: Linking to the safe bool idiom makes this the best answer by far.

Comment: Both void* and safe bool idiom work to solve my problem 99%. Is there a way that it also works doing if(aMegaInt == 0), since now this becomes ambiguous with testing for false, or for MegaInt(0)?

Comment: @didibus: safe bool idiom, when done right, doesn't make that ambiguous.  Did you try writing `operator==(int, MegaInt)` and `operator==(MegaInt, int)`?

Comment: Karisson remarks, _"comparisons ... imply an equivalence relationship that can never exist"_. Certainly `true == true`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4):

The wikipedia entry on [explicit conversion operators for C++0x](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++0x#Explicit_conversion_operators) has a decent summary of why you see this error pre-C++0x. Basically, the `bool` conversion operator is an integral conversion type, so it will be used in an integral arithmetic expression. The pre-C++0x fix is to instead use `void *` as the conversion operator; `void *` can be converted to a boolean expression, but not to an integral expression.

Comment: Though I don't think having to explicitly convert to `bool` is really much nicer, if that's the C++0x solution to the problem.

Comment: @Omnifarious: they came up with a custom kludge in the standard just for this situation :p. "However, language contexts that specifically require a boolean value (the conditions of if-statements and loops, as well as operands to the logical operators) count as explicit conversions and can thus use a bool conversion operator."

Comment: That's if C++0x ever gets released. Wasn't it renamed C++1x, because they missed the 2000-2010 schedule lol.

Answer (score 2):

As Erik's answer states, the problem here is that by providing an *implicit* conversion to `bool` you are opening the door to expressions that can mean multiple things; in this case the compiler will complain of ambiguity and give your an error.

However, note that providing an *implicit* conversion to `void*` will not let you off the hook; it will just change the set of expressions which present a problem.

There are two airtight solutions to this issue:

- Make the conversion to `bool` explicit (which can be undesirable if the class represents an entity with an intuitive "true/false" value)
- Use the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html) (this really covers all bases, but as many good things in life and C++ is way too complicated -- you pay the price)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `bool` can freely convert to `int`. So the expression `MegaInt(3424324234234342) + 5;` can equally validly be interpreted this way:

```
(bool)(MegaInt(3424324234234342)) + 5;
```

or:

```
MegaInt(3424324234234342) + MegaInt(5);
```

Each one of those expressions involves one user defined conversion and are equal in the eyes of the compiler. Conversion to `bool` is highly problematic for this reason. It would be really nice to have a way to say it should only happen in a context that explicitly requires a `bool`, but there isn't. :-/

The conversion to `void *` that someone else suggests is a workaround, but I think as a workaround it has problems of its own and I wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

```
MegaInt(3424324234234342) + 5;

MegaInt + int;
```

Should the compiler convert your MegaInt to an integral (bool is an integral type) or the integer to MegaInt (you have an int constructor)?

You fix this by creating an `operator void *` instead of an `operator bool`:

`operator void *() const { return (*this != 0) ? ((void *) 1) : ((void *) 0); }`

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned the Safe Bool Idiom. However, for objects like yours it is a bad idea to add all this nasty, special logic when you want full algebra support anyway.

You're defining a custom integer type. You get far more for your effort by defining "operator==" and "operator!=", then implementing "operator bool()" as something like:

```
operator bool()
{
   return (*this != 0);
}
```

Just from those 3 functions you get all of the "if" idioms for integers, and they'll behave the same for your custom ints as the built-in ones: "if(a==b)", "if(a!=b)", "if(a)", "if(!a)". Your implicit "bool" rule will also (if you're careful) work intuitively as well.

Besides, the full "Safe Bool Idiom" is unnecessary. Think about it- the only time you need it is "1) comparison of 2 objects is ill-defined or undefined, 2) cast to (int) or other primitive types needs to be protected and 3) object validity IS well-defined (the actual source of the returned bool)."

Well, 2) is only a consideration if you actually wish to SUPPORT casting to a numeric type like int or float. But for objects that have NO well-defined notion of equality (# 1), providing such casts unavoidably creates the risk of the very "if(a==b)" logic bombs the idiom supposedly protects you from. Just declare "operator int()" and such private like you do with the copy ctor on non-copyable objects and be done with it:

```
class MyClass {
private:
   MyClass(const MyClass&);
   operator int();
   operator long();
   // float(), double(), etc. ...
public:
   // ctor & dtor ..
   bool operator==(const MyClass& other) const { //check for equality logic... }
   bool operator!=(const MyClass& other) const { return !(*this == other); }
   operator bool() { return (*this != 0); }
};
```