# Automatic conversion from double/int/string to bool in C++

Tags: c++, boolean

I'm a Java programmer who has been trying to learn a bit of C++ on the side to expand on my knowledge. Here is a small code snippet which I *think* works due to implicit conversion but I'd like to know which part of the specification does it refer to and what are the other rules which I must be aware of when it comes to implicit conversion. Is there a document/link/site out there which lays down the implicit conversion rules?

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

int main(void) {
  using namespace std;
  vector<bool> a;
  a.push_back("asdf");
  a.push_back("");  
  a.push_back(12);  
  a.push_back(0.0);  
  copy(a.begin(), a.end(), ostream_iterator<bool>(cout, "\n"));
  return 0;
}

/*
output:

1
1
1
0
*/
```

TIA,
sasuke

Comment: That would be the language specification :)

Comment: the only rule I can give you is: try to avoid `implicit conversion` as if your life depend on it.

Comment: The most important thing to know about your code-snippet is that `vector<bool>` is a specialization of `vector` and behaves differently in several aspects (none of which are relevant to your question though, just thought you should know). Be careful when using it.

Comment: Using vector<bool> isn't recommended in C++.

Comment: @Constantinius you got that backwards

Comment: @DumbCoder: That's strange, heard it for the first time. What is recommended then?

Comment: @mkb: AFAICT, C++ standard is not freely avaiable. Is there any site which offers material very close to the C++ standard?

Comment: @sasuke: Here's one article that discusses the problems with `vector<bool>`: http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/050.htm

Comment: @sasuke the last draft before it becomes a standard is always free. Which version are you looking for? C++03 or C++11?

Comment: @sasuke: There's no problem with using `vector<bool>` as long as you understand how it differs from other specialisations of `vector` - the data is not stored as an array of `bool`, but as packed bits. If you don't need to access the underlying array (which you usually won't), then there's no problem.

Comment: @sasuke: sure it is. You can even read the text that's *more recent* than the published standard [on GitHub](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft) (you just need to TeX it yourself).

Comment: Where to find the C++ draft standard: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4653479/10077

Comment: Just one last question: if I'm using GCC 4.X or Visual Studio 2010, which standard document should I be referring? The C++03 or C++11 one?

Comment: @sasuke: For GCC, it depends on what the `X` is, and if you use the `std=c++0x` compile option. I don't think any version fully implements C++11 yet. I understand VS2010 implements some C++11 features as well. Might be best to go with C++03 for now.

Comment: @MikeSeymour "_There's no problem with using vector<bool>_" Wrong. There is a problem with `vector<bool>`: it's broken, beyond repair, should be removed, it's required for conforming implementations, but it isn't even clear that conforming implementations are allowed to provide it!!!

Comment: @curiousguy: You're correct that it doesn't formally meet the Container requirements. However, it's perfectly usable if you don't require `vector::reference` to define an actual reference type, whatever your views on whether or not it should exist in the first place. As I said, there's no problem using it as long as you understand it.

Comment: @MikeSeymour `pointer` is not a pointer, `reference` is not a reference, and once you start using `v[i].flip()` (or more subtly, if you overload a function on `vector<bool>::reference` vs `bool&`) your code is not compatible with a regular `vector` or any other regular container. And the other advantages you could get from the packing (fast binary operations): you can't even get them because the binary representation is not accessible! If you really want the packing, you can implement your own `bit_vector` based on `vector<unsigned long>`, then you don't have all these anomalies.

Comment: @curiousguy: I have asked it before in the comments and I ask it again: if not `vector<bool>`, then what?

Comment: @sasuke: `vector<char>` if you want a dynamic array of something that behaves more-or-less like `bool`; or `deque<bool>` if you want a sequence container that contains actual `bool` values; or `vector<bool>`, `boost::dynamic_bitset` (which is similar, but with a richer interface) or `std::bitset` (if the size is fixed) if you want to minimise memory usage, and don't mind that it's not a bona fide container.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Pointers and integers, and also booleans, are *integral types*. The first three are all either pointers or integers, and since they are all non-zero, they convert to the boolean value `true`. The fourth value of type `double` converts to a zero integral value and hence `false`.

Conversion of doubles that are not representable as integral values (like infinity and NaN) is undefined.

See 4.9 for details, and also 4.12 for "Boolean conversions":

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type bool. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false;
>   any other value is converted to true.

Your `0.0` is an arithmetic type of zero value.

Perhaps you may not be familiar with string literals in C++: `""` denotes the array `char[1] { 0 }`, and this array (of one element) decays to a pointer to its first element, which is necessarily a non-null pointer. Similarly, "asdf" denotes an array `char[5] { 'a', 's', 'd', 'f', 0 }`, and again this decays to a (non-null) pointer to its first element. The actual value of the characters is entirely immaterial.

Comment: Wow, supremely complicated. Is everything you mentioned in last paragraph (decaying to pointer, "" as char[1] etc.) also part of the specification (esp the char[1] part)?

Comment: Interesting fact about doubles. Is there a standard spec about that?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: Yes, I quoted it and cited relevant references.

Comment: @sasuke: It's not at all complicated, it's just a bit of a mouthful to say if you want to make an accurate statement. Most real C++ programmers have a mental shortcut, so when they see a string literal they'll think "pointer" immediately, but it's important to be accurate sometimes.

Comment: I don't see the part about doubles. "A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to false; any other value is converted to true." - this tells me any double that is not 0 is converted to true. Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: `double` is an arithmetic type, and `0.0` is a double of zero value... so you have an arithmetic type of zero value. What's unclear?

Comment: That part is clear, I don't understand "Conversion of doubles that are not representable as integral values (like infinity and NaN) is undefined.".

Comment: "_Conversion of doubles that are not representable as integral values_" most double are not representable as integral values!

Comment: @LuchianGrigore "_Interesting fact about doubles. Is there a standard spec about that?_" no, because it's (obviously) wrong! ;)

Comment: That's subjective. Even if wrong, what should it be converted to? true or false?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore Non zero values are converted to true.

Answer (score 2):

All base types can be converted to `bool` implicitly. Anything that is not `0` is `TRUE`, and `0` is `FALSE`.

For user defined types, if you use pointers, anything that is not NULL is evaluates to `TRUE`, otherwise `FALSE`.

If you use object instances and not pointers, you need to declare `operator bool()`:

```
class A
{
public:
   operator bool() {return false;};
};

//....

A a;
if ( a ) //compiles because of the operator
   //...;
```

Comment: Can you extrapolate on the last part, what do you mean by "object instances"? Something like `Person p;` instead of `Person* p;`?

Comment: @sasuke exactly. I wrote a small example.

Comment: Be aware that `operator bool()` opens a whole other can of worms - which gave rise to the [safe-bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool) in C++03. [Apparently this is obsolete now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete), though.