# If 1 == true, can you flip it?

Tags: c++

So in c++, 1 is equalavent to true

```
int test = 1;
if(test) {// returns true; enter if loop
    passgo();
    collect200dollars();
}
```

Does the flip operator (sorry for lack of better name) work on this?

```
int test = 1;
if(!test) {// returns false; do not enter if loop
...
}else{
    goToJail();
}
```

Comment: You're looking for logical negation operator, and yes, the `int` will be converted to `bool`, just like in the `if`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not only one but also all non zero values are equivalent to true. When you are writing

```
if(test)
```

it means, compiler checks if the value of test is equivalent to 0 or not. If value of test is equivalent to 0, then the if expression returns false, otherwise returns true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can check it also for false... It will negate test which is true because it is not a zero. In conversion of int to bool, If the value is not a zero then it will consider it as true otherwise it is false. In your case you assigned test = 1 that means true, and you are negating true value means if condition will directly go to execute else code..

Comment: "Of course" is a bit weird because it might very well not be intuitive. Other languages prohibit conversions between integers and booleans.

Answer (score 1):

Any fundamental numerical type (`int`, `double`, `float` etc) different from zero will be converted to a `bool` equal to `true` in a condition. So the `!` operator will negate a `bool` which is `true`, and the latter will become `false`.

See related
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8591324/3093378