# How does this conversion to bool work?

Tags: c++, cinder

I'm learning the Cinder framework.
There is a class `Texture` in this framework, and it can be used like this:

```
Texture myImage;
myImage.loadImage(/*...*/);
if(myImage)
{
    // draw the image.
}
```

I got confused about this, because `myImage` is an object. Using it as a condition doesn't make sense to me. I expected something like `myImage.exist();`. So I stepped through the code, and it turns out that `Texture` class has a conversion operator defined:

```
public:
    //@{
    //! Emulates shared_ptr-like behavior
    typedef std::shared_ptr<Obj> Texture::*unspecified_bool_type;
    // What is this???
    operator unspecified_bool_type() const { return ( mObj.get() == 0 ) ? 0 : &Texture::mObj; }
    void reset() { mObj.reset(); }
    //@}
```

Obj is defined as:

```
protected:      
    struct Obj {
        Obj() : mWidth( -1 ), mHeight( -1 ), mCleanWidth( -1 ), mCleanHeight( -1 ), mInternalFormat( -1 ), mTextureID( 0 ), mFlipped( false ), mDeallocatorFunc( 0 ) {}
        Obj( int aWidth, int aHeight ) : mInternalFormat( -1 ), mWidth( aWidth ), mHeight( aHeight ), mCleanWidth( aWidth ), mCleanHeight( aHeight ), mFlipped( false ), mTextureID( 0 ), mDeallocatorFunc( 0 )  {}
        ~Obj();

        mutable GLint   mWidth, mHeight, mCleanWidth, mCleanHeight;
        float           mMaxU, mMaxV;
        mutable GLint   mInternalFormat;
        GLenum          mTarget;
        GLuint          mTextureID;
        bool            mDoNotDispose;
        bool            mFlipped;   
        void            (*mDeallocatorFunc)(void *refcon);
        void            *mDeallocatorRefcon;            
    };
    std::shared_ptr<Obj>        mObj;
```

I know that `operator int() const` can implictly change the Object to int, but how is unspecified_bool_type working? The debugger stops at `operator unspecified_bool_type() const { return ( mObj.get() == 0 ) ? 0 : &Texture::mObj; }` when `if(myImage)` is executing.

And I may be a little confused about the grammar here, what does

```
typedef std::shared_ptr<Obj> Texture::*unspecified_bool_type;
```

mean?

And does

```
void (*mDeallocatorFunc)(void *refcon);
```

in Obj mean that mDeallocatorFunc is a member of Class Obj, a function pointer to a function with prototype: `void xxx(void *)`?

Comment: Looks like some incantation of the "safe bool idiom"...

Comment: @KerrekSB I think I got it, it defines a conversion operator which can convert `Texture` to `shared_ptr<Obj>` and the rest of the checking is provided by `shared_ptr<Obj>`. But what does `typedef std::shared_ptr<Obj> Texture::*unspecified_bool_type;` mean?? is there any difference with `typedef std::shared_ptr<Obj> unspecified_bool_type;` ? I'm confused with this kind of gramma, especially the `::*` could you help me out here? thank you very much.

Comment: That thing in particular is a pointer-to-member (which isn't an ordinary pointer!), but beyond that I haven't read enough of the code. There are many popular ways to implement the SBI, so if you search a bit you might find a description that is very similar to your code...

Comment: @KerrekSB so after `typedef std::shared_ptr<Obj> Texture::*unspecified_bool_type;` if I write `unspecified_bool_type var;` then var means a pointer to shared_ptr<Obj> and it must point to a member of Texture?

Comment: @shengy : Specifically, given `typedef std::shared_ptr<Obj> Texture::*unspecified_bool_type;`, `unspecified_bool_type` is a pointer to a data member of `Texture` of type `std::shared_ptr<Obj>`. Returning a pointer of this type does not ever instantiate a new `shared_ptr<>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [the safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html). It doesn't use simply `operator bool()` because implicit conversions can cause all kinds of trouble with that operator. So instead it uses a type that is implicitly convertible to `bool` (like a pointer to member) and that is the least dangerous possible.

Luckily this sort of hack is not required in C++11 because we can write `explicit operator bool` instead and not fall prey to implicit conversions.

Comment: Relevant: [Is the safe-bool idiom obsolete in C++11?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6242768/500104)