# Is using void* instead of bool an advisable practice?

Tags: c++, boolean, void-pointers

[Horstmann’s C++ pitfalls](http://www.horstmann.com/cpp/pitfalls.html) tackles an interesting point when talking about streams. To quote him:

> Use conversion to `void*`, not conversion to `int` or `bool`, to implement objects yielding truth values. Unlike `int` or `bool`, `void*` have no legal operations other than `==` comparison.

As a programmer, I would be puzzled if some function returned `void*` when I expect a boolean. Horstmann provides an example where using a `void*` instead of a `bool` seems appropriate. Is it always advisable?

Comment: It's advisable when is a good idea, and it is inadvisable if it is a bad idea. What sort of answer did you expect?

Comment: @KerrekSB: cases, examples, to be able to distinguish between the good practices and the bad practices, I’m a bit confused right now. Why don’t we always do that? Why don’t we just `typedef void* secure_bool`

Comment: Relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242296/conversion-function-for-error-checking-considered-good and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8809224/how-does-this-conversion-to-bool-work and http://stackoverflow.com/q/6242768/500104 (and here with examples: http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html, also linked)

Comment: Horstmann is talking about conversion operators, not return types. Your question makes no sense.

Comment: @ildjarn : The statement `Unlike int or bool, void* have no legal operations other than == comparison` is what I’m referring to, regardless of conversions.

Comment: To the downvoter: please state your point, this is how we all progress ain’t it?

Comment: I'm the downvoter, and I _did_ state my point. Horstmann is talking about giving classes implicit conversion operators (specifically `bool` vs. some pointer type), and you seem to be asking about arbitrary function return types. This makes no sense.

Comment: @ildjarn : There were 2 down votes. I was wondering about the other one. Now maybe my question was not perfectly well-stated by “is using void* instead of bool an advisable practice?” but it made sense to me.I should rephrase it with: “Horstmann shows an example where using a void* instead of a bool seems appropriate. Is it always advisable?”.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is not advised in general circumstances and, with C++11, is not advised at all.

The reason for the conversion to `void*` was to support syntax like

```
std::ifstream myStream;
if (myStream) {

}
if (!myStream) {

}
```

Here, a conversion to `bool` seems more reasonable, but leads to weirdnesses like this:

```
if (myStream == true) // ??
```

The conversion to `void*` prevents this code from being legal, but opens up a whole other can of worms, like

```
delete myStream; // ??
```

In C++11, with the ability to have `explicit operator bool()` as a member function, this `void*` hack is deprecated and should not be used.  Don't use this idiom.  If you need something to return a `bool`, have it return a `bool`.  If you need an object that can be converted to a `bool`, use `explicit operator bool`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Has the definition of `istream` changed in C++11 to use this new feature?

Comment: @Kerrek: yes. It's [a breaking change](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6399615/what-breaking-changes-are-introduced-in-c11), but one that only breaks broken code (`delete std::cin` won't compile anymore).