# Is there a "normal" unary logical operator in C++

Tags: c++, operators, logical-operators, unary-operator

I mean, we all know that there is the negation logical operator `!`, and it can be used like this:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    bool operator!() { /* implementation */ }
};

int main()
{
    Foo f;
    if (!f)
        // Do Something
}
```

Is there any operator that allows this:

```
if (f)
    // Do Something
```

I know it might not be important, but just wondering!

Comment: by defining the operator bool(), you get what you want.

Comment: @maress: Yes, we've covered that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can declare and define `operator bool()` for implicit conversion to `bool`, if you're *[careful](http://www.google.co.uk/search?ix=icb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=safe%20bool%20idiom)*.

Or write:

```
if (!!f)
   // Do something
```

Comment: I know I could do it this way, but is there no direct operator?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: How is `operator bool()` not _direct_?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: `if` requires its condition expression to be of `bool` type, so anything you give it will be converted to `bool` where possible. Same story for `if (1)`

Comment: Got it, thanks :), but what did you mean by _careful_? what should I care more about?

Comment: @Mr.TAMER: Google for ["safe bool idiom"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?ix=icb&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=safe+bool+idiom).

Answer (score 3):

Since `operator bool()` in itself is pretty dangerous, we usually employ something called the [*safe-bool idiom*](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html):

```
class X{
  typedef void (X::*safe_bool)() const;
  void safe_bool_true() const{}
  bool internal_test() const;
public:
  operator safe_bool() const{
    if(internal_test())
      return &X::safe_bool_true;
    return 0;
  }
};
```

In C++11, we get explicit conversion operators; as such, [the above idiom is obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6242768/500104):

```
class X{
  bool internal_test() const;
public:
  explicit operator bool() const{
    return internal_test();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

```
operator bool() { //implementation };
```