# Strange bool overloading

Tags: c++

Can you explain for me what the typedef here is doing and what the purpose is?

```
class C
{
    public:
        ...

        typedef bool (C::*implementation_defined_bool_type)(bool) const;

        operator implementation_defined_bool_type() const {
            return _spi ? &C::isPersistent : 0;
        }

};
```

Comment: It's an implementation of the obsolescent ["safe bool" idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete-in-c11).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> **Can you explain for me what the `typedef` is doing here?**

```
typedef bool (C::*implementation_defined_bool_type)(bool) const;
```

`typedef`s a **pointer to a const member function** of a type `C`, which takes a `bool` as input parameter and also returns a `bool`.

While,

```
operator implementation_defined_bool_type() const
```

Takes in an object of type `C` and returns a type `implementation_defined_bool_type`.
It is known as an **Conversion Operator**.

> **what is the purpose of it?**

It implements the **"Safe Bool Idiom"**, which aims to validate an object in a boolean context.
Note that the [Safe Bool Idiom is obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete-in-c11) with the C++11 Standard.

**Good Read:**
[The Safe Bool Idiom](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFwQFjAA&url=http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html&ei=jFPgT-iuH4r3rQekpcz6DA&usg=AFQjCNFFSCg8G7WxPya15C6J1iJapbPcGA)

Comment: It doesn't explain what it actually does and why it is implemented that way, it's purpose and all.