# When an object provides both `operator!` and `operator bool`, which is used in the expression `!obj`?

Tags: c++, overloading, operator-keyword

I've ran across a question I am not able to answer for myself. Also, I didn't find an answer to this on both google and here. Say, I want to "check an object for validity" in an if clause, like so:

```
MyClass myObject;

// [some code, if any]

if (!myObject)
{
    // [do something]
}
```

Let `MyClass` be defined something like this:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass() { };
    virtual ~MyClass() { };
    bool operator!()
    {
        return !myBool;
    };
    operator bool()
    {
        return myBool;
    };
private:
    bool myBool = 0;
};
```

My question now is: Which one of the overloaded operators is actually used in this if clause? Either way, the result is obviously the same.

Comment: I think it will go by the path of least resistance, and call `operator!`...

Comment: Don't think about overloading bool until you've read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete-in-c11

Comment: Yes, just do the `operator bool` one and make it explicit. Anyway, `operator!` requires no conversions. `operator bool` requires a user-defined conversion.

Comment: @doctorlove perfectionism ftw! done :-)

Comment: Just a question: does it really make sense to use `operator bool()`?  This is probably one of the most frequent abuses of operator overloading (including in `std::ios_base`); a member function `isValid()`, or whatever, is far clearer.

Comment: @JamesKanze look at the discussion with Peter below. Conversion operators are used to convert an object into any desired type.

Comment: You could just run it through a compiler and see what your compiler thinks it should be...

Comment: @poljpocket Who said anything different?  The question is whether such a use is operator overload abuse, or whether it results in obfuscation.  It's very rare for an object to be `true` or `false`, and if you wouldn't say that the object is true in everyday English, then overloading `operator bool` is abuse, and should be avoided.  The fact that there is a precedent for it in the standard library doesn't make it good engineering.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It will use `operator!`.

A function whose parameter types match the arguments will be chosen in preference to one that requires type conversions.

Answer (score 2):

You'll find that `operator !` gets executed because it's the most direct resolution. If it used `operator bool` instead then it would have to call the conversion operator first, and then apply the `!` separately to that.

As a general rule, it's a good idea to avoid that situation though. It's generally better just to define the `bool` conversion, because strictly speaking that's what you want your logical operators to act on, rather than `MyClass` directly. Defining both creates a bit of a readability problem, and is a form of redundant code duplication (which can lead to programmer error in future).

Comment: I don't agree with the redundancy you described in the last part. `operator bool()` is a conversion operator. So a statement like `bool myTest = myObject;` without the `operator bool()` present doesn't work.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I meant that defining `operator bool` **and** `operator !` is effectively code duplication, because you're needlessly replicating the same (albeit inverted) logic.