# Overloading logical NOT operator vs bool type-cast operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, not-operator

Consider the following code:

```
class Truth
{
public:
    Truth(bool val) : value(val) {}
    bool operator!() {std::cout<<"operator!()"<<std::endl; return !value;}
    operator bool() {std::cout<<"operator bool()"<<std::endl; return value;}
private:
    bool value;
};

int main()
{
    Truth t(true);

    if(!t)
        std::cout<<"t is false"<<std::endl;
    else
        std::cout<<"t is true"<<std::endl;

    if(!!t)
        std::cout<<"t is false"<<std::endl;
    else
        std::cout<<"t is true"<<std::endl;

    if(t)
        std::cout<<"t is false"<<std::endl;
    else
        std::cout<<"t is true"<<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In the statements `if(!t)` and `if(!!t)` the overloaded `operator!()` implementation gets called, whereas (not surprinsingly) in the statement `if(t)` the overloaded `operator bool()` implementation gets called instead.

However if the `operator!()` implementation is commented out, in all 3 statements, `operator bool()` gets called.

I understand the "why" this happens, but my concern is that, overloading logical NOT operator (!) seems to miss half of the truth evaluation semantics while `bool` type-cast operator appears to cover them nicely.

Am I missing something or should the overloading of logical NOT operator be discouraged in favor of bool type-cast?

Comment: I see where you're going, but it would also be confusing for `operator!` to be called when `if (t)` has no !

Comment: @chris, totally agree, which is why I am guessing overloading `operator!` should be discouraged. Wouldn't you say?

Comment: I can't say I can think of any useful straightforward overloads off the top of my head. I'm sure you can find all kinds of *not* straightforward ones in Boost, but that's the same with every operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C++11, you can simply overload `explicit operator bool()`. There's no reason to overload `operator!` unless you want it to do something different - and if you think you want that, you should probably think again.

Historically, overloading `operator bool` would open the door to implicit conversion to any numeric type, which could cause confusion, ambiguities, and subtle bugs; so it was better not to do that. Overloading `operator!` was a simple way to allow some use in conditionals, without opening that door, if you didn't want to get bogged down with the [safe bool idiom](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Safe_bool). (The link is for historical interest only; the idiom [is obsolete in C++11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete-in-c11), thanks to explicit conversion operators.)