# why is std::cout convertible to void* if using g++?

Tags: c++, pointers, implicit-conversion, ostream

Why can one cast a `std::ostream` to a `void` pointer? I am not aware of any such conversion operator in `std::ostream`. Code below

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    void *p = std::cout; // why does this work? 
}
```

I'm asking this question since I've seen a placement operator `new` invoked as

```
Foo* pFoo = new (std::cerr) Foo;
```

and have absolutely no idea why would one write such a thing.

PS: I am compiling with g++ 4.9.2 with or without `-std=c++11`. clang++ **does not accept the code**.

PSS: Found out that due to the so called "safe bool problem" (see @nicebyte's answer), in pre C++11 a `void*` conversion operator was defined for `std::ostream`, which was then removed in C++11. However, my code compiles fine in C++11 using g++. More than that, clang++ rejects it no matter what version of the standard I use, even with `-std=c++98`, although my understanding is that it should accept if compiled as pre-C++11.

Comment: `new (std::cerr) Foo` ? What. The. Hell.

Comment: @Quentin :) that's what I told myself when I saw that.

Comment: I would love it if you could provide the source. I can only think of horrible things this could lead to.

Comment: It's in Scott Meyers' book "Effective C++", item 52, page 291 (3rd edition)

Comment: Well I learnt something today, thanks ! That's a strange critter for sure...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_cast) (your question is answered in the very last section, "*The safe bool problem*").

To elaborate a bit, the implementation defines an implicit conversion to `void*` defined for things like `std::cin` and `std::cout`, just so that code like `while(std::cin>>x){...}` compiles, while code like `int x = std::cin;` doesn't. It's still problematic because you can write stuff like in your example.

C++11 solves this problem by introducing explicit conversions.

An explicit conversion operator looks like this:

```
struct A {
 explicit operator B() { ... } // explicit conversion to B
};
```

When A has an explicit conversion to B, code like this becomes legal:

```
A a;
B b(a);
```

However, code like this is not:

```
A a;
B b = a;
```

A construct like `if(std::cin)` requires `cin` to be converted to `bool`, the standard states that in order for the conversion to be valid in that particular case, code like `bool x(std::cin);` should be "legal". Which can be achieved by adding an explicit conversion to `bool`. It allows cin/cout to be used in the above context, while avoiding things like `int x = std::cout;`.

For more information, refer to [Bjarne's page](http://www.stroustrup.com/C++11FAQ.html#explicit-convertion) as well as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete-in-c11).

Comment: I have edited my answer to provide more detail (and included information on C++11 as well).

Comment: @nicebyte, thanks, was aware of explicit operators, but didn't know that there is a `void*` conversion operator for `std::ostream`. However, in C++11 it seems that this `void*` conversion was eliminated, due to the introduction of explicit conversion to `bool`. However my code still works even with `-std=c++11` in `g++`, so I guess it's a flaw in the libstdc++ implementation. In clang++, even if I use `-std=c++98`, the code still does not compile.

Comment: I don't think the standard explicitly states that cin/cout MUST be implemented to use explicit conversion to bool. It might also be that g++ has left in the implicit void* conversion because of some weird backwards compatibility considerations.

Comment: @nicebyte: excellent answer. Thanks for giving cppreference link in ur answer.

Answer (score 4):

Answering only the follow-up, since nicebyte's answer is perfect for the original question.

Chances are, your gcc is set up to use libstdc++ (which hasn't changed the operator yet due it being an ABI-breaking change), and your clang is set up to use libc++ (which was from the beginning intended as a C++11 standard library and isn't quite conformant in C++98 mode - it provides a bool conversion operator that is explicit in C++11).

Answer (score 2):

I think it's to allow for `if (std::cout) ...` without allowing for implicit conversion to `bool`, or something like that.

Comment: IIRC, this answer appeared in the *low quality post* review queue. I categorised it as *not an answer* because of the use of *I think* and *something like that*, for me it looked like a comment, not an answer. But I don't know C++, I'm sorry if this is a valid answer and if it was a mistake to flag it.