# Overloading cast to bool enables casting to int

Tags: c++11, enums

Consider following class used to wrap enum

```
class A {
    int v;
    A(int v) : v(v) { }
public:
    enum B : int { X = 1, Y = 2, Z = 3 };
    A(B v) : A(static_cast<int>(v)) { }
    A operator|(const A &b) const { return v | b.v; }
    operator bool() const { return v; }
};

int main() {
    A a(A::Y);
    if (a) 
        return 1;
    a = a | A::X; // this line failes to compile
    return 0;
}
```

I get an error on the marked line about ambigous overload

```
1.cpp:15:11: note: candidates are:
1.cpp:15:11: note: operator|(int, int) <built-in>
1.cpp:7:7: note: A A::operator|(const A&) const
```

If i comment out the bool cast operator the ambigous overload error goes away, so I suggest ambiguity arose from following casting path

```
(A)a -[operator]-> (bool)a -[implicit?]-> (int)a
```

Is there a way to resolve this ambiguity?
The bool operator is used to allow

```
if (a) ...
```

and I'd rather stick to it than use something like

```
if (!!a) ...
```

with operator!().

Comment: What if you make the cast operator `explicit`?

Comment: Wow, that worked, thanks. Mind posting an answer so i could accept it?

Comment: But why does that work implicitly in `if(a)`?

Comment: Found the answer in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete-in-c11