# Redirecting std::cin directly to std::cout

Tags: c++, io

An exercise about standard io asks me to:

> Read input from the standard input and write it to the standard output.

A possible solution is:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using std::cin; using std::cout;
using std::string;

int main()
{
    string word;
    while (cin >> word)
        cout << word;

    return 0;
}
```

The string acts as a buffer in this example. If one tries to get rid of the buffer by doing something like this:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cin; using std::cout;

int main()
{
    while (cout << cin)
        ;
    return 0;
}
```

the results are very different. When I run this code I get an interminable stream of

> 0x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d300x600d30

on the terminal.

Why this happens? Why do these programs behave differently?

Comment: How did you get `cout << cin` to compile?

Comment: I don't see this [compiling](http://ideone.com/3ZzFWd)

Comment: @scohe001 https://ideone.com/zRMP7G compiles perfectly

Comment: I am using g++ 4.8.2 on linux mint debian edition. I used no flags, just (g++ example.cpp -o example).

Comment: @Andrey What did you do differently??

Comment: @scohe001 I choose just "C++" while you "C++14". Dunno what is the difference for this particular case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`cout << cin` will not *work* the way you want it to.  In C++11 and later, it won't even compile.

You are seeing an unfortunate side-effect of the (now obsolete) ["safe bool" idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768).

Before C++11, a `std::istream` [could be implicitly converted to a `void*` to emulate bool semantics.](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool)  (Since C++11, `explicit operator bool() const` fills that role)

Therefore, the code:

```
while (cout << cin)
```

compiles in C++98 or C++03, because it can be implicitly converted to:

```
while (cout << static_cast<void*>(cin) )
```

This cast is allowed to produce any non-NULL `void*` when `cin` is not in an error state.  In your case, it is producing the pointer `0x600d30`.

Comment: +1, but telling how one can accomplish the OP's desired behavior would grant you a +2 (if I could vote twice).

Comment: @EnricoMariaDeAngelis I'm inclined to agree, but in this case the OP has already shown desired behavior in the question, and is only asking why `cout<<cin` does what it does.

Answer (score 1):

In first solution, you extract a string from cin and reinject it in cout. But in the second way, compiler tries to convert cin into a value suitable for injection in cout.

Your implementation converted cin to a pointer and repeatedly printed it. Mine simply converted cin to a bool and repeadedly prints `1`.

But beware, even your first version is not transparent to multiple spaces or tabs, and would probably not respect lines either. I would prefer:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <string>


int main()
{
    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(std::cin, line)) {
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```