# What is the purpose of operator RestrictedBool in QScopedPointer?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I read through the code for `QScopedPointer` and came across something that I haven't been able to make sense of.

Here's the pertinent code from [`QScopedPointer`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/corelib/tools/qscopedpointer.h?h=5.7) on code.qt.io:

```
template <typename T, typename Cleanup = QScopedPointerDeleter<T> >
class QScopedPointer
{
    typedef T *QScopedPointer:: *RestrictedBool;
public:
...
#if defined(Q_QDOC)
    inline operator bool() const
    {
        return isNull() ? Q_NULLPTR : &QScopedPointer::d;
    }
#else
    inline operator RestrictedBool() const
    {
        return isNull() ? Q_NULLPTR : &QScopedPointer::d;
    }
#endif
...
inline bool isNull() const
{
    return !d;
}
...
protected:
    T *d;
```

I understand the preprocessor definition that makes QDoc think `QScopedPointer` has an `operator bool` instead of `operator RestrictedBool`. What I don't understand it what purpose `RestrictedBool` serves and how it does it. For example, a simpler implementation is:

```
inline operator bool() const
{
    return !isNull();
}
```

**In short:** What's happening here? Why is `operator RestrictedBool` underhandedly returning the address of `d` and why does it exist in the first place instead of `operator bool`?

Comment: I would say it is the Qt way of `explicit operator bool` (pre c++11).

Comment: it is restricted to explicit conversions

Comment: [this](http://lists.qt-project.org/pipermail/development/2012-January/001433.html) made me find [this](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html) which seems to explain the idea behind it

Comment: @tobi303: that does explain it, thank you. I'll accept if you or someone else wishes to write it up as an answer.

Comment: I should summarize if I have it correctly: `operator bool` returns an rvalue of `bool` that can be used for other operations. `RestrictedBool` is a private typedef of a pointer to `d`. Using it as the type for an operator means it can be used in an `if` statement, but not with other comparison operators.

Comment: it was also rather new to me (well, i heard about it but long time ago) and I didnt want to write an answer without reading it in detail. I would suggest you post your summary as an answer.

Comment: Thank you @tobi303, I did just that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is an implementation of the **Safe Bool Idiom**, explained [here](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

The naive implementation:

```
inline operator bool() const
{
    return !isNull();
}
```

returns an rvalue of `bool` that can be implicitly used for other operations, e.g.

```
QScopedPointer<Foo> foo(nullptr);
int i = 1;
if (foo < i)
    ...
```

is valid code.

**Summary:** `RestrictedBool` is a *private* `typedef` of a pointer to the type of `d`. Using it as the return type for an operator means it can be used in an if statement (`if (foo)`), but cannot be used with other operators.

**Note:** [C++11 allows the use of `explicit operator bool`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete-in-c11), which eliminates the need for the Safe Bool Idiom in C++11 or later code. An implementation for `QScopedPointer` in C++11 might look like this:

```
explicit operator bool() const
{
    return !isNull();
}
```

Thank you to tobi303 and Jarod42 for providing the basis for this answer.

**Further reading regarding C++11 and the Safe Bool Idiom:**

- [Chris's C++ Thoughts - Contextually converted to bool](http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.it/2013/07/contextually-converted-to-bool.html)
- [Is the safe-bool idiom obsolete in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete-in-c11) - SO question
- [Very explicit operator bool](https://www.kdab.com/explicit-operator-bool/) - a writeup specific to QScopedPointer

Comment: Heh, did you say something like https://codereview.qt-project.org/#/c/158069/ ? :-)

Comment: Am I incorrectly assuming that the explicit bool still allows `if (foo)`?

Comment: Okay. I nixed the C++11 reference since I definitely need to read up on how `explicit operator bool` works.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6242768/is-the-safe-bool-idiom-obsolete-in-c11 and http://chris-sharpe.blogspot.it/2013/07/contextually-converted-to-bool.html

Comment: I've elaborated on this issue here https://www.kdab.com/explicit-operator-bool/ .